# jquery add method and implementation

Tags: jquery, validation, forms, passwords

Ok so from my previous post I got a lot of good feedback. I am starting this one so that I can start a new question and add the full code I have. i know something is messing up, but here is my method and implementation.

```
jquery.validator.addMethod("passwordRules", function(input) {
    var reg = /^{^%\s]{6,}$/;
    var reg2 = /[a-zA-Z]/;
    var reg3 = /[0-9]/;
    return reg.test(input) && reg2.test(input) && reg3.test(input);
});
```

that is my add method. here is how I am trying to apply it to the new password field. My question here is do i use required? I am lost.

```
$("<%= NewPass1.GetName() %>").validate({
    rules:{
        required: { passwordRules: true }
}, messages: {
    "<%= NewPass1.GetName() %>": {
required: WrapError("Invalid", "The password contains invalid....")}
  }
});
```

I just need to reassure that the password box only allows min of 6 chars, no spaces or %, at least one number and at least one letter.

Comment: Please correct this "reg2.text(input) to reg2.test(input)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define a new method, you simply have to use the method name as a key in the rules set like this:

```
$("<%= NewPass1.GetName() %>").validate({
    rules:{
        passwordRules: true
    }
});
```

d.